# How to create fulltext index with parser ngram in knex?

Tags: knex.js

I'm using MySQL 8.0.31. I want to create a fulltext index with ngram parser in the schema builder:

```js
knex.schema.createTable('clusters', (table) => {
    table.string('name').notNullable();
    table.index('name', 'name_text_idx', {
        indexType: 'FULLTEXT',
        // WITH PARSER ngram
    });
});
```

But I don't know how to add the `WITH PARSER ngram` part to the [options](https://knexjs.org/guide/schema-builder.html#index). How to create the index in knex?

EDIT:

Currently I can use `raw()` after `createTable()` to do it, but I want to know whether it's possible to do it in `createTable()`, maybe using the `index()` method.

```js
knex.schema
    .createTable('clusters', (table) => table.string('name').notNullable())
    .raw('ALTER TABLE `clusters` ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `name_text_idx` (`name`) WITH PARSER `ngram`');
```

Comment: the `FULLTEXT ` index type doesn't exist with the available index types so I made it as native query as you have done. I think that It has to be added to support mySQl as well as its support Postgres refers to the documentation.